# Spread two images vertically inside one div

Tags: javascript, html

I have two similar images inside one fixed size div. Images are placed one under another. I want to spread images vertically in order to one img stick to top, and another stick to bottom.

```
<div style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid black;'>text
    <div style='border:1px solid black;height: 150px;'>
        <img style='float: left; clear: both;' src='http://iconizer.net/files/Sketchdock_Ecommerce_Icons/orig/arrow-up-blue.png'>
        <img style='float: left; clear: both;' src='http://iconizer.net/files/Sketchdock_Ecommerce_Icons/orig/arrow-down-blue.png'>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: do you have an example?  do you want them evenly separated, or do you want one to be stuck to the top and one stuck to the bottom?  We need more information.

Comment: [Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@**Teemu** is right.

- Add `position: relative;` to parent DIV.
- Add `position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px; left: 0;` to second `img`.

Run snippet below:

```html
<div style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid black;'>text
    <div style='position: relative; border: 1px solid black; height: 150px;'>
        <img style='float: left; clear: both;' src='http://iconizer.net/files/Sketchdock_Ecommerce_Icons/orig/arrow-up-blue.png' />
        <img style='float: left; clear: both; position: absolute; bottom: 2px; left: 0;' src='http://iconizer.net/files/Sketchdock_Ecommerce_Icons/orig/arrow-down-blue.png' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give some more infos regarding the situation. If the images for example are of the same dimmensions then its easier to resolve this issue, if they have different dimmensions some css tweakings need to be done before achieving the desired result.

Comment: Let's assume they have same size.